# How to build properly regex?

Tags: python, python-re

I can't figure out what the problem is and why my regular doesn't work.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in fileone:
        if re.match(r'\"C:\\Program Files \(x86\)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome\.exe\" --type',line):
            pass
        else:
            if line not in filetwo:
                outFile.write(line)
```

The abowe code should match all below rows and pass it:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type
```

Comment: it's the same string every time, why you need regex? can't we directly compare the string content during conditional check ?

Comment: Nope, there are long different strings - https://i.imgur.com/neEOl2i.png

Comment: `if line.startswith('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type'):`

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: It's working, if `line.startswith('"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" --type'):`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for your use-case as you have a common string. Instead you can use `str.startwith()` to match whether your string starts with any specific string. For example:

```
>>> "my string".startswith("my")
True

>>> "my string".startswith("string")
False
```

Hence your code will become:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in fileone:
        #       vvvvvvvvv updated here
        if line.startswith('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type'):
            pass
        else:
            if line not in filetwo:
                outFile.write(line)
```

OR could be even more simplified as:

```
my_string = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type'

with open('output.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in fileone:
        if not line.startswith(my_string) and line not in filetwo:
            outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: If I need to make a lot of exceptions, it's not the best solution for me.

Comment: @test_qweqwe but you don't need exceptions based on what you mentioned in your question. If you have some other requirements, please mention it in the question. Else without knowing it would be difficult for us to handle all your use-case